# pivot_longer and uncount a dataset with many columns in R

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

This is a chunk of a huge dataset I have:

```
appartments <- structure(list(year = c(2003L, 2012L, 2014L, 2011L, 2009L), city = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E"), rooms = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L), empty = c(4L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), spacebel30 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), space3150 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), space5170 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), space7190 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), space91110 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), space111130 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), space131plus = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), spaceunknown = c(4L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 3L), bighouse = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), smallhouse = c(4L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), bothhouse = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), otherhouse = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), before1920 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), b19211950 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), b19511980 = c(4L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L), b19811910 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 2L), b2011 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), renovated = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), old = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), new = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), rent = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), sale = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), rentsale = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), r1000 = c(3L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), r10001250 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), r12511500 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), r15011750 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), r17512000 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L), r20012250 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), r2251b2500 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `25012750` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), r27513000 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), r30003250 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), r32513500 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), runknown = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), r3500plus = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

It has information about flats for every year, a certain city and the number of rooms. But after that, the sum is already aggregated: The number of empty flats, after that the number of certain spaces (from 30qm till unkown), then the number of four different types of house, after that the number of old/new/renovated, then rent/sale/both and finally the number of priceranges from <1000 till >3500.

Or in short: It's an ugly mixture of tidy and wide, of raw and aggregated data.

So I wanted to pivot_longer the last five groups first, but thats immpossible to achive(at least for me). Uncount first does not work either, I get instantly thousand of repeating rows. Put it in five separate df does not work, because I have nothing to join it afterwards.

My goal: thousands of simple records, one for each flat:

| year | city | rooms | empty | space | housetype | buildyear | old-new | payrent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2003 | A | 2 | no | space3150 | bighouse | before1920 | old | r1000 |
| 2020 | B | 4 | no | space91110 | smallhouse | b2011 | new | r15011750 |
| 2011 | C | 1 | yes | space5170 | otherhouse | b19511980 | renovated | r12511500 |
| 2020 | B | 3 | no | space91110 | otherhouse | b2011 | new | r15011750 |

...and so on.

It's probably a bit like unscramble scrambled eggs, but still: Is it possible to achive?

Comment: I think there will be situations where you won't know the correct data, but could come up with multiple possible interpretations. For instance, a row might say 4 empty, two of which old and two of which new, and two for rent and two for sale. Are the old ones for rent, or are the new ones for rent, or one of each?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a try:

Please check double. I am not sure about the result, because in all groups there is the same data.

```
library(tidyverse)

appartments %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(year, city, rooms, empty)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(space = ifelse(str_detect(name, "space"), name, NA_character_),
         housetype = ifelse(str_detect(name, "house"), name, NA_character_),
         buildyear = ifelse(str_detect(name, "before|b\\d+"), name, NA_character_), 
         old_new = ifelse(str_detect(name, "old|new|renovated"), name, NA_character_),
         payrent = ifelse(str_detect(name, "r\\d+"), name, NA_character_)) %>% 
  select(-name, -value) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(year, city, rooms, empty)) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  group_by(year, city, rooms, empty, name) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
  select(-row) %>% 
  data.frame()
```

```
   year city rooms empty        space  housetype  buildyear   old_new    payrent
1  2003    A     1     4   spacebel30   bighouse before1920 renovated      r1000
2  2003    A     1     4    space3150 smallhouse  b19211950       old  r10001250
3  2003    A     1     4    space5170  bothhouse  b19511980       new  r12511500
4  2003    A     1     4    space7190 otherhouse  b19811910      <NA>  r15011750
5  2003    A     1     4   space91110       <NA>      b2011      <NA>  r17512000
6  2003    A     1     4  space111130       <NA> r2251b2500      <NA>  r20012250
7  2003    A     1     4 space131plus       <NA>       <NA>      <NA> r2251b2500
8  2003    A     1     4 spaceunknown       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r27513000
9  2003    A     1     4         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r30003250
10 2003    A     1     4         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r32513500
11 2003    A     1     4         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r3500plus
12 2012    B     2     1   spacebel30   bighouse before1920 renovated      r1000
13 2012    B     2     1    space3150 smallhouse  b19211950       old  r10001250
14 2012    B     2     1    space5170  bothhouse  b19511980       new  r12511500
15 2012    B     2     1    space7190 otherhouse  b19811910      <NA>  r15011750
16 2012    B     2     1   space91110       <NA>      b2011      <NA>  r17512000
17 2012    B     2     1  space111130       <NA> r2251b2500      <NA>  r20012250
18 2012    B     2     1 space131plus       <NA>       <NA>      <NA> r2251b2500
19 2012    B     2     1 spaceunknown       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r27513000
20 2012    B     2     1         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r30003250
21 2012    B     2     1         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r32513500
22 2012    B     2     1         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r3500plus
23 2014    C     5     1   spacebel30   bighouse before1920 renovated      r1000
24 2014    C     5     1    space3150 smallhouse  b19211950       old  r10001250
25 2014    C     5     1    space5170  bothhouse  b19511980       new  r12511500
26 2014    C     5     1    space7190 otherhouse  b19811910      <NA>  r15011750
27 2014    C     5     1   space91110       <NA>      b2011      <NA>  r17512000
28 2014    C     5     1  space111130       <NA> r2251b2500      <NA>  r20012250
29 2014    C     5     1 space131plus       <NA>       <NA>      <NA> r2251b2500
30 2014    C     5     1 spaceunknown       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r27513000
31 2014    C     5     1         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r30003250
32 2014    C     5     1         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r32513500
33 2014    C     5     1         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r3500plus
34 2011    D     2     2   spacebel30   bighouse before1920 renovated      r1000
35 2011    D     2     2    space3150 smallhouse  b19211950       old  r10001250
36 2011    D     2     2    space5170  bothhouse  b19511980       new  r12511500
37 2011    D     2     2    space7190 otherhouse  b19811910      <NA>  r15011750
38 2011    D     2     2   space91110       <NA>      b2011      <NA>  r17512000
39 2011    D     2     2  space111130       <NA> r2251b2500      <NA>  r20012250
40 2011    D     2     2 space131plus       <NA>       <NA>      <NA> r2251b2500
41 2011    D     2     2 spaceunknown       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r27513000
42 2011    D     2     2         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r30003250
43 2011    D     2     2         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r32513500
44 2011    D     2     2         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r3500plus
45 2009    E     4     3   spacebel30   bighouse before1920 renovated      r1000
46 2009    E     4     3    space3150 smallhouse  b19211950       old  r10001250
47 2009    E     4     3    space5170  bothhouse  b19511980       new  r12511500
48 2009    E     4     3    space7190 otherhouse  b19811910      <NA>  r15011750
49 2009    E     4     3   space91110       <NA>      b2011      <NA>  r17512000
50 2009    E     4     3  space111130       <NA> r2251b2500      <NA>  r20012250
51 2009    E     4     3 space131plus       <NA>       <NA>      <NA> r2251b2500
52 2009    E     4     3 spaceunknown       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r27513000
53 2009    E     4     3         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r30003250
54 2009    E     4     3         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r32513500
55 2009    E     4     3         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>  r3500plus
```

Comment: Thank you, I will have to check this with the real dataset....